# Iterate mediator-expression using property

Tags: loops, xpath, wso2, expression, wso2-esb

I want to use iterator mediator by passing property as Xpath in expression. is that possible in wso2 esb

```
<property name="listXPath" value="//records/record"></property>
<iterate continueParent="true" expression="get-property('listXPath')" id="EventListId" sequential="true">
  <target>
    <sequence>
      <log>
        <property name="inside Iterator for Each List" expression="$body"></property>
      </log>
    </sequence>
  </target>
</iterate>
```

i want the result as iterator should accept property as a expression parameter

Answer (score 0):

Guess this would not work.
But You can try to use Sequence template and pass your Xpath as a param to a call-template mediator.

Answer (score 0):

You can set XPath for expression in iterate mediator. WSO2 EI documentation [1] explains how to achieve it. If you scroll down the documentation you will find an example in which they have used XPath in expression of iterate mediator.

If you specifically want to have a property because there is a change in the body. You can preserve the body on which you want to iterate in a property and apply the value of that property to body right before the iterate mediator and then directly use XPath to iterate the body.

[1] https://docs.wso2.com/display/EI600/Iterate+Mediator